# Take off axis labels

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgfplotstable

How can I take off the labels my axes in the following graph? I want to just show the circle-parabola system with no numbers on the axes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}


\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[domain=-10:10, samples=100,grid=major,
    restrict y to domain=-2:2,xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$, legend pos=south west]
\addplot [color=red]    {-sqrt(1-x^2};
\addplot [color=red]    {sqrt(1-x^2};
\addplot [color=blue]  {(x-2)^(1/2)};
\addplot [color=blue] {-(x-2)^(1/2)}; 

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can take off the ticks labels with `ticks = none`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}


\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[domain=-10:10, samples=100,grid=major,
    restrict y to domain=-2:2,xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$, legend pos=south west, ticks=none]
\addplot [color=red]    {-sqrt(1-x^2};
\addplot [color=red]    {sqrt(1-x^2};
\addplot [color=blue]  {(x-2)^(1/2)};
\addplot [color=blue] {-(x-2)^(1/2)}; 

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the axis ticks and grids as in you MWE, but without ticklabels, just use `yticklabels=\empty` and `xticklabels=\empty` in the axis options.